# Android camera2 manual flash doesn't always work

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm using the new camera2 api on Android 6.1, sdk 23.

I have two requests: a preview and a still image capture request.  I'd like to make it so that the flash goes off on every still image request, but without any pre-flash.  Right now, my request looks like this:

```
CaptureRequest.Builder requester = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(mCameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        requester.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);
        requester.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT_STILL_CAPTURE);
        requester.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED);
        requester.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
        requester.addTarget(mCaptureBuffer.getSurface());

mCaptureSession.capture(requester.build(), null, null);
```

It seems to work on one phone (a Motorola Moto G) but not on another (a Nexus 5 -- the flash doesn't turn on at all).  I know the Nexus' flash works because I can trigger it with other camera apps, so I'm guessing there are some defaults that I'm not setting.

Is there another way I can do this / more flags I can set?

Thanks!

Edit:

---

It turns out that a lot of the trouble I was having stemmed from working with devices that had only `LIMITED` support for camera2.  Just because you can access the camera using camera 2 doesn't mean you can control all the features.  Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30967026/1115876) answer for more

Comment: maybe you have piece of example? or just tell me where exactlly i should to incdlude this lines of code? on `stillCapture()` or `onConfigurate()` or `unlockFocus()` medhod? because i can't find anythink that can make my code worked...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Flash_Mode` and `CONTROL_AE_MODE` sometimes have some problems when they are active at the same time, so I recommend you to separate them, keeping off `FLASH_MODE` to off and control the Flash with `CONTROL_AE_MODE` . So to set the different flash modes, use something like this:

```
int flashMode = yourDesireFlashModeKey;
        if (flashMode == CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF) {
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);

        } else if (flashMode == CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH) {
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);

        } else if (flashMode == CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH) {
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);

        } else if (flashMode == CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH_REDEYE) {
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH_REDEYE);
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        }
        else if (flashMode == CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF || flashMode == CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH) {

            builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        }
        else if (flashMode == CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH) {

            builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
```

Keep `FLASH_MODE` in SINGLE for `ALWAYS_FLASH`, and OFF when you are using the `AE_MODE_FLASH` Modes.

You can read more about it in [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#FLASH_MODE).

Comment: maybe you have piece of example? or just tell me where exactlly i should to incdlude this lines of code? on `stillCapture()` or `onConfigurate()` or `unlockFocus()` medhod? because i can't find anythink that can make my code worked...

Comment: auto flash still not working for video recording.. any other option? pls help

Comment: I guess the 2 last `else if` blocks will never execute, so I don't understand  why it's present here.

Comment: 2 if for `CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH`

Answer (score 0):

```
mPhotoRequestBuilder.set(
                                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
                                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON
                            )
                            mPhotoRequestBuilder.set(
                                CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
                                CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH
                            )
```

Answer (score -1):

Manual flashMode update can be done with this

I see ImageCapture.flashMode only has effect during we build with initial configuration, ImageCapture.Builder() etc.
But if you want to enable/disable flash dynamically, you will have to use the following.

```
camera?.cameraControl?.enableTorch(enableFlash)
```

If you are wondering what camera is? Captured it from documentation.

```
// A variable number of use-cases can be passed here -
// camera provides access to CameraControl & CameraInfo
camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture
)
```