# How to find out if the current device has camera2 api support or not

Tags: android

I am using camera2 api in my application but some of the device like Redmi note 3 are not supporting it even when these devices are using lollipop android version. Now my query is how would I check if the device has camera2 api support or not in my app

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31240881/5985958) answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below code
Check if you have Front Camera in your device

```
public static boolean checkCameraFront(Context context) {
 if(context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Check if you have Rear Camera in device

```
public static boolean checkCameraRear() {
int numCamera = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
if(numCamera > 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: But that can be checked for camera api of android also ... How could it differentiate the support for camera2 api support and camera api support in any device.

Comment: what you want to checked  ? Please upload some code which you have tried

Comment: I was referring this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31240881/6460582 but how to find out if the device has camera2 api support.

Answer (score 0):

All Android devices that have passed certification support the camera2 API starting in API level 21 (Lollipop).

Some devices may not support all the possible features such as manual control or RAW capture, but the basic API should always work.

Comment: Ya you are right camera preview starts always on lollipop devices but on some devices like redmi note 3 the image doesn't get captured on hitting capture button ... Now how I can solve that ... Other lollipop devices are working fine with the same

Comment: There may be device-specific bugs, but basic image capture really should work. But debugging would require full system logs of the app run.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit [this](https://github.com/PkmX/lcamera) i hope it's could be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Here's snippet to determine which cameras in the device have Full or Limited Camera2 API support (just call checkCamera2Support method):

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        public boolean allowCamera2Support(int cameraId) {
            CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            try {
                String cameraIdS = manager.getCameraIdList()[cameraId];
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraIdS);
                int support = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL);

                if( support == CameraMetadata.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY )
                    Log.d(TAG, "Camera " + cameraId + " has LEGACY Camera2 support");
                else if( support == CameraMetadata.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED )
                    Log.d(TAG, "Camera " + cameraId + " has LIMITED Camera2 support");
                else if( support == CameraMetadata.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL )
                    Log.d(TAG, "Camera " + cameraId + " has FULL Camera2 support");
                else
                    Log.d(TAG, "Camera " + cameraId + " has unknown Camera2 support?!");

            return support == CameraMetadata.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED || support == CameraMetadata.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL;
        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void checkCamera2Support() {
        if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ) {
            if( getNumberOfCameras() == 0 ) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "0 cameras");
            }else {
                for (int i = 0; i < getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
                    if (!allowCamera2Support(i)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "camera " + i + " doesn't have limited or full support for Camera2 API");
                    }else{
                        // here you can get ids of cameras that have limited or full support for Camera2 API
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public int getNumberOfCameras() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            return manager.getCameraIdList().length;
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(AssertionError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```