# Is it possible to use Android's old camera and new camera2 API concurrently?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-camera, cordova-plugins, android-camera2

In my ionic3 project I am using the `cordova-plugin-camera-preview` plugin for accessing the camera which is based on the old camera API. But I would like to focus manually which is a feature possible only through the new `camera2` API. So far I couldn't find a Cordova plugin written for the new `camera2` API.

I was wondering if it is possible to continue using the existing plugin and possibly write another small Cordova plugin (or maybe a function in the existing plugin) using the `camera2` API only for setting the focus manually? That way, I won't have to re-write the whole plugin again.

In other words, can I capture a photo using `camera` API with a focus set using `camera2` API?

Comment: @RameshSambu: Thanks for the corrections and improvements.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to? Just import both classes and use them

Comment: Actually, there is no need to import them both if you apply a min sdk level of 21. But you do need check out this answer specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/31240881/320111 (do not use the accepted answer, use the answer I'm linking to).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk From the link provided, I understand that one can use both APIs. But, if I am not wrong, if I have a capture session started using the `camera` API, I will be able to use the `camera2` API only for calling function like `getCameraCharacteristics()` & `getCameraIdList()` because the functions do not interfere with the capture session from the `camera` API. What I wont be able to do is also start a capture session with `camera2` API.
@cricket_007 So I will not be able to set focus using `camera2` API & at the same time capture photo with that focus value using the `camera` API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the APIs don't have any way to hand off a camera device between them. Once you open a camera with the old API, you're stuck with it until you close it and reopen it with camera2, or vice versa.  And that close/reopen takes a second or so, and doesn't generally preserve camera settings.

The operating models of the two APIs aren't really compatible enough to make this kind of thing feasible, as nice as it would be otherwise.  Far too many gotcha corner cases would pop up.

Comment: Exactly as I thought. Thanks for affirmation Eddy.