# Android Things Camera Hardware Support Level

Tags: android-things

I am wondering if anyone can tell me what level of camera support is included with the camera included in the NXP i.MX7D Starter Kit.  Specifically if anyone with a kit could tell me what the CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL is, I would be most grateful.

Alternatively, if anyone has attempted to set a fixed gain, exposure and frame rate before capturing and processing images, I would love to hear if that is possible.
Thanks!

Comment: [CameraCharacteristics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics)

Comment: It essentially supports the Camera2 API, so I'll be surprised if it's different from the wayt to do it on a phone.

Comment: Yes, it supports the Camera2 API, but within the Camera2 API there are different levels of hardware support.  For instance, some devices will only allow for very basic control, while others have a full set of manual controls.  You can see details on how to find the supported hardware level in this [answer to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31240881/10415098), and a little more background on the differences in support [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/android/camera2-api-level-your-android-phone/)